# hidden attribute not working when using foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, hidden

I´m trying to hide a foundation styled button, but the hidden attribute does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/foundation-5.5.1/css/foundation.css">
    <script type="application/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="../js/foundation-5.5.1/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div  class="button success" hidden="true">Button</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I hide the button?

Comment: Use css display:none; property, and try

Comment: try `aria-hidden="true"`

Answer (score -1):

Instead using `hidden="true"` you may use the `display="none"` if you wanna make the div and the space that it ocupes disappear or you can use `visibility="hidden"` if u wanna make only the div disappear.

Display example: [display="none"](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_display_none)
Visibility example: [visibility="hidden"](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_visibility_hidden)

Answer (score -2):

Try `aria-hidden="true"`. Read other options here in tutorial:

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/visibility.html